# How to combine two match patterns with guards in Python

Tags: python, pattern-matching

Consider the following case:

```py
match var1:
    case enum.A if var2 == 1:
        {code block}
    case enum.B if var2 == 2:
        {code block}
    ...
```

Here `{code block}` is exactly the same code, which I don't want to repeat.

Is there a nice way of doing a fall-through or combining these two cases without refactoring `{code block}` into a function?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. See https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#guards _"once the pattern or patterns in the case block succeed, the expression in the guard is evaluated"_ so you can't e.g. `(enum.A if var2 == 1 | enum.B if var2 == 2)` because the case and the guard are syntactically distinct items,  and there is no fall-through for empty cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired effect by matching on tuples:

```
match (var1, var2):
    case (enum.A, 1) | (enum.B, 2):
        {code block}
    ...
```

---

In a comment you additionally asked:

> What if the second case is `case enum.B if var2 in {2, 3, 4, 5}:`?

In this case you may use a nested pattern, analogous to the [example shown in PEP 636](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#capturing-matched-sub-patterns):

```
match (var1, var2):
    case (enum.A, 1) | (enum.B, (2 | 3 | 4 | 5)):
        {code block}
    ...
```

(Credits go to [RomanPerekhrest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76682239), I did not know this before.)

Answer (score 2):

Use combined sub-patterns on enum `value`s:

Sample:

```
from enum import Enum
class E(Enum):
    A = 'A'
    B = 'B'

v1 = 'B'
v2 = 3

match (v1, v2):
    case (E.A.value, 1) | (E.B.value, (2 | 3 | 4 | 5)):
        print('ok')
    case _:
        print('pass')
```

---

```
ok
```

Comment: Why is `.value` needed?

Comment: @mkrieger1, try to run my sample without `value`

Comment: You have to use `.value` because you use `Enum` and not `StrEnum` for `E`.

Comment: I mean obviously if you use `v1 = 'B'` then `.value` is needed, but I thought the assumption was that `v1 = E.A` or `v1 = E.B`.